# SQL script won't auto commit

Tags: sql, sql-server

Just want to know if the following is the correct way to write SQL script that uses BEGIN TRANSACTION? (something that works like DML)

```
BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRANSACTION
        /* SQL statements here */
    COMMIT TRANSACTION
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    IF @@ERROR <> 0
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
END CATCH
```

Whenever i tried execute it in SQL server, the script ran but somehow it won't commit the transaction. I still have to manually commit with the COMMIT TRANSACTION.

In my SQL Server Management Studio 2012, i did checked the SET_IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS to avoid autocommit when developing the script. But since i already put the statement COMMIT TRANSACTION if all statements ran successfully, then by right my script should autocommit right? Unless if i got mistaken here.

Comment: Suggest check your script for another, non-concluded `BEGIN TRAN`. Also, do a `SELECT @@TRANCOUNT` before and after running your script to detect imbalances - it should be zero in both cases.

Comment: you don't need `IF @@ERROR <> 0` before the `ROLLBACK Transaction`. If need be you can check the transaction state using `XACT_STATE()`. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189797.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `IF @@ERROR <> 0` in your `CATCH` block. When the control shifts to the CATCH block it implies an error had occurred. you can directly do a rollback like this

```
IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0 
ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
```

If need be you can check the transaction state using [`XACT_STATE()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189797.aspx).

In your catch block you can then log errors in some table or THROW the error back using `THROW` or `RAISERROR` based on your requirement and sql server version which you are using.

**Edit**

There are differences when you have `IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS ON` vs `IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS OFF`

As per [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187807.aspx) for `IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS ON`:

> When IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS = ON an explicit BEGIN TRANSACTION will start two nested transactions.

*Test Table for script*

```
CREATE TABLE test_table( a int)
```

Run the same script with `SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS OFF` and `SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS ON`

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
SELECT @@TRANCOUNT
INSERT INTO test_table VALUES(1)
SELECT @@TRANCOUNT
COMMIT
SELECT @@TRANCOUNT
```

**Output** with `SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS OFF`

```
-----------
1
-----------
1
-----------
0
```

**Output** with `SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS ON`

```
-----------
2
-----------
2
-----------
1
```

Because when `SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS ON`, there are 2 open transactions and only one commit, it seems like the commit transaction doesn't do anything.

For more info on Error Handling, see the reference links below:

- 3 Part Series by Erland Sommarskog on [Error Handling](http://www.sommarskog.se/error_handling/Part1.html)
- Article on [Error Handing in SQL Server 2012](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/handling-errors-in-sql-server-2012/) by Robert Sheldon

Comment: The catch part is not really that important for now. I just want to know why it won't autocommit based on my post above. It should autocommit with the COMMIT TRANSACTION even if i disabled autocommit in my SQL Server Management Studio right?

Comment: before your `BEGIN TRAN` set `SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS OFF
` and check `@@TRANCOUNT` as well. it should be 0

Comment: So i take it, it won't autocommit if the SET_IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS is set to on?

Comment: If you have `IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS ON`, it will create another transaction implicitly when the first DDL / DML is encountered. hence you will have 2 transactions and you are only committing 1 of those. hence it will look like the commit doesn't do anything.

Comment: yes, when you have `IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS ON` and `begin transaction`, you need to commit twice

Answer (score 0):

Use this Code:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
  BEGIN TRY
/* SQL statements here */
 COMMIT TRANSACTION
  END TRY
  BEGIN CATCH
ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
 SELECT 
    ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber
    ,ERROR_SEVERITY() AS ErrorSeverity
    ,ERROR_STATE() AS ErrorState
    ,ERROR_PROCEDURE() AS ErrorProcedure
    ,ERROR_LINE() AS ErrorLine
    ,ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage;
  END CATCH
```

As ur Sql statement runs inside
Begin..end try block:
1)if no error occurs it automatically executes **Commit Transaction** and get out of **try block**.
2)If it got error in statement inside **TRY BLOCK** it directly jumps to **BEGIN CATCH** block and Entire transaction Rollbacks there using **ROLLBACK TRANSACTION** placed there and Shows type of **ERROR MESSAGE** inside **CATCH BLOCK**.

Using this code there is not need to commit Transaction manually.
it will automatically commits if there is no error.

Comment: I don't really care about the error details, i just want that if its error, then rollback immediately and show simple error message, and if its success, then it will auto commit the script immediately. But based on your reply, i take it that BEGIN TRY should be inside the BEGIN TRANSACTION right?

Comment: This code will do exactly what you need.I have tried this format in my Live server and its working fine(100% working ).Just try it out. Yes  BEGIN TRY should be inside the BEGIN TRANSACTION .

Comment: But will it autocommit if SET_IMPLICIT_TRANSACTION is set to on?

Comment: If SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS ON ,BEGIN TRAN will make  Nested(two) transaction to start.So one transaction will be autocommit by my code.another transaction will left aside.So better use my code with "SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS OFF".it performs will as per your requirement. i'm pretty much sure about this.